# How to use export in react while using react cdn

Tags: reactjs, import

I am unable to use import while using react with cdn. Is there any specific way to use import while using react with cdn.

Comment: Next time show your code and what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot adding `type="module"` attribute to `script` tag:

```
<script type="module" src="..."></script>
```